# Random Movements in Chess

Tags: probability, random-walk, chessboard

This is a problem that I just thought of and could not find online- nor any similar problem.

Suppose we have two different chess piece stationed on opposite corners of a chess board. For this example, let's put a rook on the 'top left' and a knight in the 'bottom right'. The rook randomly moves to one of the legal positions and then the knight moves to a random legal position.

Eventually, one piece is bound to capture the other. What is the probability that the rook is the piece to capture the knight? What is the expected number of moves for this to happen in? Obviously the probability of the knight capturing the rook is just 1-probability of the other way around, but does the expected number of moves change?

I wouldn't really even know how to go about trying to solve this outside of running Monte Carlo simulations to approximate the value (fairly trivial with code).

Any suggestions of how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think with two rooks you can do a decent analysis, but I suspect a knight and a rook will take too much effort to be any fun. Specifically because the knight behaves so differently depending on what square it stands on (having either 2 or 3 or 4 or 6 or 8 available squares to move to).

Comment: What happens if the rook tries to jump over the knight? If that counts as a take, the rook has a large advantage in taking first

Comment: Two rooks is balanced - you’d just get something really close to 50%. Two knights surprisingly aren’t balanced due to parity, so the second knight is guaranteed to take the other.

Comment: @Eric the rook wouldn't be able to jump over the knight because that wouldn't be a legal move

Comment: @Eric The only thing unbalancing the two rooks is second mover advantage. There is a 1/7 chance the first took moves into the range of the second rook on the first move.

Comment: @EvanSemet If a rook is on a corner square and the knight is on an adjacent square, what would be the probability the rook takes the knight that round?  Would it be $1/2$ or $1/8$?  (this is closely related to Eric's question, but specifically I'm wondering how we determine the rook's random walk)

Comment: In theory, this is just a Markov process with 64^2 states, so it’s as “simple” as getting the sparse 4096x4096 matrix, finding the absorbing states, and plugging it into the formulas for an absorbing Markov Chain.

Comment: @BrianMoehring 1/8 because there are 8 legal moves

Comment: @Eric Without any reductions for symmetry, I think $2\cdot 63 \cdot 64+2=8066$ states?  Probably $2\cdot 63\cdot 10+2 = 1262$ with symmetry taken into account. But unless we actually program it, I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Ehh, sure. Throw a factor of two in there because of person going and reduce some because of overlap.